# How can I change the Windows 10 version 1803 shutdown sequence?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, windows-10-v1803

Since I updated Windows 10 to version 1803, there is a change in the shutdown behavior. Once I click shutdown the system switches off the display although it is still busy with the rest of the shutdown. I want it instead to switch off the display last thing as a sign the shutdown has completed and it's now safe to switch off the power.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Mine does not do that, maybe a video driver issue? But my hibernation is turned off also.

Comment: This has happened to me since the very first windows 10 version.

Comment: What do you mean by `"as a sign the shutdown has completed, and it is now safe to switch the power off"` Do you actually physically turn off or unplug the computer each time you use it? Regardless, I'd rely on watching the power on the case to be off because you then for sure know it is off.

Comment: @Run5k make your comment an answer please.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, every time a Windows 10 Feature Update is installed (e.g., version 1709 or 1803), it re-enables the **Fast Startup** function. Try to disable Fast Startup and see if that alleviates the problem:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Select `Power Options`

   [image: Power Options]
3. Select `Additional power settings` on the right

   [image: Additional power settings]
4. Select `Choose what the power buttons do` on the upper-left

   [image: Choose what the power buttons do]
5. Select `Change settings that are currently unavailable`

   [image: Change settings that are currently unavailable]
6. Scroll to the bottom of the window and uncheck the box associated with `Turn on fast startup`

   [image: Turn on fast startup]
7. Click the button to `Save changes`
8. Reboot your system

([Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/))